# ImportError: No Module named six; six already installed

Tags: python, macos, six

I'm running python 3.6 on Mac OS X El Capitan.

I'm trying to run code that uses the six module, but am getting the following error:

`ImportError: No module named six`.

When I search for six it appears no problem, and I've made sure that the location is included in the sys.path

```
$ pip show six
Name: six
Version: 1.10.0
Summary: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/
Author: Benjamin Peterson
Author-email: benjamin@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /usr/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

However, when I try to run something basic I encounter an error:

```
$ python -c "import six; print (six.__version__)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'six' has no attribute 'version'
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and have tried installing using `$ python -m pip install six`, but nothing has worked.

If anyone has any ideas or needs more information, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I had a similar problem with pytz at the weekend, uninstalling using pip then reinstalling fixed for me :)

Comment: after installation, see if six is installed by `pip list`

Comment: `pip list` does show `six (1.10.0)` installed, but the error persists

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well to. None of the Answers to date have helped either. I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 17.04.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
pip install --ignore-installed six
```

more info here:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165

Comment: I tried running this and got the following error:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six-1.10.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'`

I also tried to `sudo pip install --ignore-installed six` and even though it appeared to install correctly, I am still not able to run the original code - I continue to see `ImportError`

Comment: Permission error means you just that. Try adding `--user` tot he command and read the provided link

Answer (score 8):

I recently updated macOS Monterey 12.4 and I was facing same issue

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

So I have installed 'six' using below command

```
brew install six
```

This resolved the issue. Hope this will be useful for someone, who is not able to do import or do not have 'pip'.

Comment: Yeah, got the same while installing streamlink through ```brew install streamlink``` on Monterey 12.6.7. This fixed the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see any method version() for six from [six Documentation Release 1.10.0](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/six/latest/six.pdf), and the error you got also says six doesn't have the attribute which makes sense to me, below I print all the attributes and there's `__version__` inside

```
>>> import six
>>> six.__dir__()
['_moved_attributes', 'remove_move', '__path__', '__author__', '_MovedItems', 'Module_six_moves_urllib', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_robotparser', 'raise_from', '_SixMetaPathImporter', 'get_function_code', 'callable', 'absolute_import', '_func_code', 'moves', '_urllib_error_moved_attributes', 'text_type', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse', 'iteritems', 'iterlists', 'print_', '_assertCountEqual', '__builtins__', 'sys', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_error', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_request', 'assertRegex', 'MovedModule', 'create_bound_method', '_urllib_robotparser_moved_attributes', '_func_closure', 'indexbytes', 'string_types', 'with_metaclass', 'reraise', 'exec_', 'assertRaisesRegex', 'types', 'python_2_unicode_compatible', 'get_function_globals', '_LazyModule', '_assertRaisesRegex', '_meth_self', 'itertools', '_LazyDescr', 'BytesIO', 'add_move', 'iterbytes', '_func_defaults', '__file__', 'unichr', 'get_method_function', 'create_unbound_method', 'get_unbound_function', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_response', 'functools', '__doc__', 'assertCountEqual', 'integer_types', 'PY34', '_importer', '__spec__', '_urllib_response_moved_attributes', 'Iterator', 'StringIO', '_import_module', '__package__', '__version__', 'get_function_defaults', 'operator', 'PY3', 'MAXSIZE', 'int2byte', '_urllib_request_moved_attributes', '_urllib_parse_moved_attributes', 'b', 'class_types', 'next', 'itervalues', '_add_doc', 'viewkeys', 'MovedAttribute', 'advance_iterator', '__cached__', 'u', '__loader__', '_func_globals', 'get_method_self', 'PY2', 'iterkeys', 'wraps', '_meth_func', 'byte2int', 'io', 'viewitems', 'viewvalues', '__name__', 'get_function_closure', 'binary_type', 'add_metaclass', '_assertRegex']
>>> six.__version__
'1.10.0'
```

Therefore you can get the version of six by

```
 python -c "import six; print (six.__version__)"
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense why version() was not working. When I run

`python -c "import six; print (six.__version__)"` 

it correctly prints 1.10.0, but the `ImportError` still persists

Comment: how can that be possible if the module is not imported ? Try use python shell and see what happens

Comment: I should clarify - running the small code mentioned here works no problem.

The code I'm having issues with starts with `from six import string_types` and I'm seeing an `ImportError` here.

Comment: @Lucas13 `string_types` are constants, you use it directly: `six.integer_types`, now you should be good

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow - are you saying I should replace `string_types` used in the code with `six.string_types` and not import the module `six`?

Comment: @Lucas13 use `import six` and then when you need string_types  just call `six.string_types`

Comment: I'm still seeing the same `ImportError` when using `import six` in the other file. Now that I can tell `import six` works for a different file though it seems my error is likely coming from something different

Answer (score 1):

For those not finding any of the above answers taking care of your issue - python3.10 will require you in some cases to call pip+python version so...

my fix was: `pip3.10 install six`

And ta-da! Six ***IS/WAS*** installed for python3 (if you have overlapping versions) but it was ***NOT*** installed for the current version of python.

You can check if this will solve your issue because when you enter: `pip3 --version` you will likely not see the same version that python3 is calling.

**If you see this:**

```
pip3 --version
pip 23.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

but your `python3 --version` shows you:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.10.9
```

(or mis-matched versions of python3 and pip3) **you will get your issue resolved using my answer.**

(You can check to see the version Python3 alias calls by using: `which python3`)

Answer (score 0):

The issue I ran into was the script I was running was using Python 2.7, and I was using 3+ on my machine. After switching to Python 2.7 using venv, everything worked correctly.