# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves.collections_abc'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

i am just starting with machine learning i am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbXj7091OWA) from Weights&Bias where they gave us  some code and asked to run it i am unable to run the code

First I was getting the error

> Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher

for which I tried this method

Following the advice given here, downgrading Keras did the trick for me without having to touch any other packages. Just do:

```
pip install keras==2.3.0
```

from this link

[Error "Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465620/error-keras-requires-tensorflow-2-2-or-higher)

then I started getting the error

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "perceptron-single.py", line 6, in <module>
import wandb
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\wandb\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
from wandb import sdk as wandb_sdk
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
from .wandb_config import Config  # noqa: F401
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\wandb_config.py", line 10, in <module>
from six.moves.collections_abc import Sequence
*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves.collections_abc'
```

for which I tried this method

```
easy_install six
```

from this link

[ImportError: No module named six](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967428/importerror-no-module-named-six)

but it did not solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

Using this method

```
pip install --ignore-installed six
```

From the following link solved the problem for me.

[ImportError: No Module named six; six already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658258/importerror-no-module-named-six-six-already-installed)

Although I still don't understand about what was actually wrong and how it got fixed.