# Importing stix2, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves.collections_abc'

Tags: python

I have issues importing the stix2 library regardless of the code I have written.

Following https://github.com/oasis-open/cti-python-stix2, I followed the installations instructions and performed

```
pip install stix2
```

I used Anaconda, Jupyter Notebook to run my python script.

When importing stix2

```py
import stix2
```

I get the error *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves.collections_abc'*

```py
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-2e32347d9df3> in <module>
----> 1 import stix2

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stix2\__init__.py in <module>
     27 from .confidence import scales
     28 from .datastore import CompositeDataSource
---> 29 from .datastore.filesystem import (
     30     FileSystemSink, FileSystemSource, FileSystemStore,
     31 )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stix2\datastore\filesystem.py in <module>
      9 import six
     10 
---> 11 from stix2 import v20, v21
     12 from stix2.base import _STIXBase
     13 from stix2.datastore import (

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stix2\v20\__init__.py in <module>
     15 # flake8: noqa
     16 
---> 17 from .base import (
     18     _DomainObject, _Extension, _Observable, _RelationshipObject, _STIXBase20,
     19 )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stix2\v20\base.py in <module>
      1 """Base classes for STIX 2.0 type definitions."""
      2 
----> 3 from ..base import (
      4     _DomainObject, _Extension, _Observable, _RelationshipObject, _STIXBase,
      5 )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stix2\base.py in <module>
     17     MissingPropertiesError, MutuallyExclusivePropertiesError,
     18 )
---> 19 from .markings import _MarkingsMixin
     20 from .markings.utils import validate
     21 from .utils import (

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stix2\markings\__init__.py in <module>
     20 
     21 
---> 22 from stix2.markings import granular_markings, object_markings
     23 
     24 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stix2\markings\granular_markings.py in <module>
      4 from stix2.markings import utils
      5 from stix2.utils import is_marking
----> 6 from stix2.versioning import new_version
      7 
      8 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stix2\versioning.py in <module>
      7 
      8 import six
----> 9 from six.moves.collections_abc import Mapping
     10 
     11 import stix2.base

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves.collections_abc'
```

Running the command "pip list" in the user home directory of the Anaconda command prompt verifies that stix2 and six is installed.

```
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- ---------
alabaster                          0.7.12
anaconda-client                    1.7.2
anaconda-navigator                 1.9.7
anaconda-project                   0.8.3
antlr4-python3-runtime             4.8
asn1crypto                         1.0.1
astropy                            3.2.1
atomicwrites                       1.3.0
attackcti                          0.3.3
attrs                              19.2.0
Babel                              2.7.0
backcall                           0.1.0
backports.functools-lru-cache      1.5
backports.os                       0.1.1
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0
backports.tempfile                 1.0
backports.weakref                  1.0.post1
beautifulsoup4                     4.8.0
bitarray                           1.0.1
bkcharts                           0.2
bleach                             3.1.0
bokeh                              1.3.4
boto                               2.49.0
Bottleneck                         1.2.1
certifi                            2019.9.11
cffi                               1.12.3
chardet                            3.0.4
Click                              7.0
cloudpickle                        1.2.2
clyent                             1.2.2
colorama                           0.4.1
comtypes                           1.1.7
conda                              4.7.12
conda-build                        3.18.9
conda-package-handling             1.6.0
conda-verify                       3.4.2
contextlib2                        0.6.0
cryptography                       2.7
cycler                             0.10.0
Cython                             0.29.13
cytoolz                            0.10.0
dask                               2.5.2
decorator                          4.4.0
defusedxml                         0.6.0
distributed                        2.5.2
docutils                           0.15.2
entrypoints                        0.3
et-xmlfile                         1.0.1
fastcache                          1.1.0
filelock                           3.0.12
Flask                              1.1.1
fsspec                             0.5.2
future                             0.17.1
gevent                             1.4.0
glob2                              0.7
greenlet                           0.4.15
h5py                               2.9.0
HeapDict                           1.0.1
html5lib                           1.0.1
idna                               2.8
imageio                            2.6.0
imagesize                          1.1.0
importlib-metadata                 0.23
ipykernel                          5.1.2
ipython                            7.8.0
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0
ipywidgets                         7.5.1
isort                              4.3.21
itsdangerous                       1.1.0
jdcal                              1.4.1
jedi                               0.15.1
Jinja2                             2.10.3
joblib                             0.13.2
json5                              0.8.5
jsonschema                         3.0.2
jupyter                            1.0.0
jupyter-client                     5.3.3
jupyter-console                    6.0.0
jupyter-core                       4.5.0
jupyterlab                         1.1.4
jupyterlab-server                  1.0.6
keyring                            18.0.0
kiwisolver                         1.1.0
lazy-object-proxy                  1.4.2
libarchive-c                       2.8
llvmlite                           0.29.0
locket                             0.2.0
lxml                               4.4.1
MarkupSafe                         1.1.1
matplotlib                         3.1.1
mccabe                             0.6.1
menuinst                           1.4.16
mistune                            0.8.4
mkl-fft                            1.0.14
mkl-random                         1.1.0
mkl-service                        2.3.0
mock                               3.0.5
more-itertools                     7.2.0
mpmath                             1.1.0
msgpack                            0.6.1
multipledispatch                   0.6.0
navigator-updater                  0.2.1
nbconvert                          5.6.0
nbformat                           4.4.0
networkx                           2.3
nltk                               3.4.5
nose                               1.3.7
notebook                           6.0.1
numba                              0.45.1
numexpr                            2.7.0
numpy                              1.16.5
numpydoc                           0.9.1
olefile                            0.46
openpyxl                           3.0.0
packaging                          19.2
pandas                             0.25.1
pandocfilters                      1.4.2
parso                              0.5.1
partd                              1.0.0
path.py                            12.0.1
pathlib2                           2.3.5
patsy                              0.5.1
pep8                               1.7.1
pickleshare                        0.7.5
Pillow                             6.2.0
pip                                20.2.4
pkginfo                            1.5.0.1
pluggy                             0.13.0
ply                                3.11
prometheus-client                  0.7.1
prompt-toolkit                     2.0.10
psutil                             5.6.3
py                                 1.8.0
pycodestyle                        2.5.0
pycosat                            0.6.3
pycparser                          2.19
pycrypto                           2.6.1
pycurl                             7.43.0.3
pyflakes                           2.1.1
Pygments                           2.4.2
pylint                             2.4.2
pyodbc                             4.0.27
pyOpenSSL                          19.0.0
pyparsing                          2.4.2
pyreadline                         2.1
pyrsistent                         0.15.4
PySocks                            1.7.1
pytest                             5.2.1
pytest-arraydiff                   0.3
pytest-astropy                     0.5.0
pytest-doctestplus                 0.4.0
pytest-openfiles                   0.4.0
pytest-remotedata                  0.3.2
python-dateutil                    2.8.0
pytz                               2019.3
PyWavelets                         1.0.3
pywin32                            223
pywinpty                           0.5.5
PyYAML                             5.1.2
pyzmq                              18.1.0
QtAwesome                          0.6.0
qtconsole                          4.5.5
QtPy                               1.9.0
requests                           2.22.0
rope                               0.14.0
ruamel-yaml                        0.15.46
scikit-image                       0.15.0
scikit-learn                       0.21.3
scipy                              1.3.1
seaborn                            0.9.0
Send2Trash                         1.5.0
setuptools                         41.4.0
simplegeneric                      0.8.1
simplejson                         3.17.2
singledispatch                     3.4.0.3
six                                1.15.0
snowballstemmer                    2.0.0
sortedcollections                  1.1.2
sortedcontainers                   2.1.0
soupsieve                          1.9.3
Sphinx                             2.2.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp            1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-devhelp              1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp             1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-jsmath               1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp               1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml      1.1.3
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.1.2
spyder                             3.3.6
spyder-kernels                     0.5.2
SQLAlchemy                         1.3.9
statsmodels                        0.10.1
stix2                              2.0.2
stix2-patterns                     1.3.1
sympy                              1.4
tables                             3.5.2
taxii2-client                      2.2.2
tblib                              1.4.0
terminado                          0.8.2
testpath                           0.4.2
toolz                              0.10.0
tornado                            6.0.3
tqdm                               4.36.1
traitlets                          4.3.3
typed-ast                          1.4.1
unicodecsv                         0.14.1
urllib3                            1.24.2
wcwidth                            0.1.7
webencodings                       0.5.1
Werkzeug                           0.16.0
wheel                              0.33.6
widgetsnbextension                 3.5.1
win-inet-pton                      1.1.0
win-unicode-console                0.5
wincertstore                       0.2
wrapt                              1.11.2
xlrd                               1.2.0
XlsxWriter                         1.2.1
xlwings                            0.15.10
xlwt                               1.3.0
zict                               1.0.0
zipp                               0.6.0
```

I have also tried

```
pip install --ignore-installed six
```

From this link:
[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves.collections_abc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64357732/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-six-moves-collections-abc)

But it still does not work. What's the issue?

Comment: Add more information to your question, everything that one might need to answer. About the platform, have you installed it etc

Comment: In any case, this may not be a programming question but rather something worth of a bug report. It's impossible to tell though, because you didn't include a [mcve] in your question. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @AryanParekh I have added a little more information to my post. May I know if there is anything else I can add?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you for your suggestions. As for a reproducible example, I have commented out all of my code except "import stix2" and the issue still arises. I will find out how I can make a bug report.

Comment: ...and how did you install that software? After all, *something* seems to be there, but not enough of it to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to https://pypi.org/project/six/#files
2. download "six-1.14.0.tar.gz (33.9 kB)"
3. unzip it, copy and paste "six.py" into your source directory
4. import "six" module into your source code(import six)
5. run source script.

Comment: What does source directory refer to? Is it "~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stix2"?

Answer (score 1):

Created a new python script and ran the code there instead. It worked. Weird bug.